# Use exec node in Node-RED while running Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, node-red

I have been trying to run the exec node in Node-RED, hoping that it would use the command prompt native to Windows 10. I would provide a command that would run a python script I have. If the command went through, my windows button would be clicked. Node-RED says "Successfully Deployed" when I run my single exec node, but the windows button does not pop up. I am concluding that Node-RED does not know how to access the Windows command prompt, which is very frustrating. Is there a way to run python scripts from Node-RED while running Windows?

In case it is relevant, I am using Node-RED to communicate with the bluetooth low energy protocols of the Lightblue Bean Arduino board. I am sure that there is not a python library for communicating with bluetooth low energy for Windows. For Mac and Linux, sure, it's implemented by [Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE). But they say they do not have anything for Windows.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked someone and they told me you cannot have a standalone exec node- you need to use an inject node to get everything going. I checked off "Inject once at start?" and my script ran just dandy.